# NodeJs net.Socket() events not firing

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

Trying to write a TCP client in Node v0.10.15 and I am having a little trouble getting data back from the server.  I know that the server is working properly because I have 3-4 different clients written in different languages communicating with it.

Below is a snippet of a larger piece of code but this should get the point across.
The problem is:  I'm expecting 2 packets coming back after writing to the socket (this part is not included in this example).  I'm only seeing the "data" event being fired once.  Is there something that I need to do to get node to resume reading from the Tcp stream?  I can confirm that the server is sending 2 packets(The length and then the actual data)  Any help would be appreciated.

```
var dc = require('./DataContracts.js');
var net = require('net');
require('buffertools').extend();
var client = net.Socket();
var isConnected = false;
var serverHost = '10.2.2.21';

var dataCallback;
var receivedBuffer = new Array();

function InitComm(buffer) {

    if (!isConnected) {
        client.connect(4987, serverHost, function() {

            client.on('data', function(data) {

                console.log('Received server packet...');
                var buf = new Buffer(data);
                receivedBuffer.push(buf);

                client.resume();

            });

            client.on('end', function() {
                if (receivedBuffer.length > 1) {
                    if (dataCallback !== undefined)
                        dataCallback(receivedBuffer);
                }
            });

            client.on('close', function() {
                //clean up 
            });

            client.on('error', function(err) {
                console.log('Error!: ' + err);
            });

            Communicate(buffer);

        });
    } else {
        Communicate(buffer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that node was combining both of the packets together.  I must be missing a Carriage return on the first packet

Comment: may i know the fix or what's the error! i too have same confusion,when the remote TCP connection is closed no events are fired in the code